# zooming in to a wms feature in OL3

Tags: openlayers-3

I have an application where I have all the ids of the building. When I click the id in my application it sends id to my openlayers application. In my openlayers application I have a map layer for building (WMS layer).

What I need is to when i click the id it opens the OL and zoom to the specific building with the id.

Can anyone suggest how can i achieve this? I can't send coordinate to my OL application because my other application has MySql as DB and it doesn't have coordinates field. The only common attribute in this case is building id (both in my other application and OL application).

AJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cant request features from a WMS based on ID, you need to know the location of a feature in order to do a getfeatureinfo request (if the server is allowing this operation).

Have you created the WMS service or where is it served from? Is it possible for you to serve another service (like WFS) instead? This would allow you to query features by id.

WFS reference
http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs

In that case when querying a layer for buildingID= bb21 you can put the following in your request:

```
http://yourhost/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:buildings&PROPERTYNAME=id&CQL_FILTER=id='bb21'
```

Comment: I created the wms layer from shape file. I guess i can load the layer as WFS too, I haven't checked that option yet. Can you point out how this can be achieved using WFS layer? :)

Comment: are you using geoserver? in that case read this:
http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.0/user/services/wfs/reference.html#getfeature
if you can provide store/layer/attribute-info i can construct a query for you

Comment: oh yes i forgot to mention. I am using geoserver 2.7.1

Comment: what do you mean? like what?? :)

Comment: please read my updated answer and accept it if this helped you

Comment: var u="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?&service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=genesis:Building_WGS";
var v=new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Boundary',
           source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: u,
    crossOrigin:"Anonymous",
                format: new ol.format.WFS({
                })
            })  
});
i have problem while adding layer as WFS in my application. What's wrong??

Comment: I have loaded my layer as vector layer. Now How do i use that URL?